# How to select the next dropdown menu using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I need to select the second, third and up to last dropdown menu selenium python.

I can select the first dropdown menu, but don't know how to select the next dropdown menu. 
For selecting the first dropdown menu I used the following command

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver =webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://pmfby.gov.in")
driver.maximize_window()
em = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Calculator")
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
ActionChains(driver).click(em).perform()
Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")).select_by_index(2)
```

The webpage screenshot as follows:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrTk.png)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please add the html of the dropdown which you want to select

Comment: https://pmfby.gov.in/  From this I chose the "Insurance Premium Calculator " option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dropdown `placeholder` text is same for all the dropdown present on the page, you can make one generic function to select value from the dropdown and call it wherever needed.

You can do it like:

```
def select_dropdown_value(dropdown_number):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//select[@placeholder='Select Pack'])["+dropdown_number+"]")))
    select.select_by_index(1)
```

And now you can call this function by sending the `dropdown_number` in it for which it will select the value from that dropdown on the page.
You can call this function like:

```
select_dropdown_value(1) or
select_dropdown_value(2)
```

And here, you can parameterise the index number as well, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can  just index into the webElements list returned by the form-control class. That is faster than xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pmfby.gov.in")
driver.maximize_window()
em = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Calculator")
em.click()
dropDowns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.form-control')

for i in range(len(dropDowns)):
    dropDowns[i].click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to select each such drop-down menu. Your script only clicking the first dropdown menu. Anyway, the problem already solved. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No it clicks all of them

Comment: Arrange your windows side by side and you will see it click each dropdown. This is also a faster method as modern browsers are optimized for css selectors and class selector is the second fastest selector method.