# Enter a value in a text box after selecting options in dropdown menu using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, textbox

This question is related to my previous post (link: [click to view the previous post in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293560/how-to-select-the-next-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-python)). After selecting the options for each dropdown menu the last option will pop up as a text box. I want to enter an integer on the textbox corresponds to "Area (In Hectare)" textbox. [Screenshot is given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKABc.png)

After that, I need to click the "Calculate" button also.  Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter the value in the text box using the following xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Area')]").send_keys('1')
```

And then you can click on the Submit button using the following xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: Wow.. it is working well. Thank you so much for your help.