# For loop dropdown menu in Selenium using Python for years and months

Tags: loops, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, extract

I have created this process to extract data from customs, here I have several dropdown menus, I am interested in creating a for loop to select "year" (año - in Spanish) and "month" (mes in Spanish), and then download the data.  I am able to create for one year and one month, but it is tedious if I want to do it for several years.  I tried different solutions here (some just select the year in the for loop but then it does not include the month), here is the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('')  # Provide the path to the chromedriver if not in PATH
# Open the webpage
driver.get("https://www.aduanas.gob.do/estadisticas/dinamicas/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]/option[4]')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="month"]')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="month"]/option[9]')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="type"]')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="type"]/option[2]')
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="App"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div[4]/button/img')
button.click()
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="App"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div/a')
button.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

The solutions I have found and partially work are: [How to select the next dropdown menu using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293560/how-to-select-the-next-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-python)

tried the code:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.aduanas.gob.do/estadisticas/dinamicas/")
driver.maximize_window()
em = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]')
em.click()
dropDowns = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]/option[2]')


for i in range(len(dropDowns)):
    dropDowns[i].click()
```

But it says object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Any help is really appreciated.

Please find the following image to be clear:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: 'WebElement' has no len() is caused by the 'dropDowns = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]/option[2]')' line, find_element returns an instance of the WebElement class. In order to select all elements (i.e. list), you have to use 'find_elements' method. But in general, I didn't really understand the question, tbh. Can you attach an image of your dropdowns (the site is not reachable), to at least get some clue about the issue you are facing.

Comment: See picture in question, as you can see there are several years to select (same applies to months), and what I need is that you select year, but if I do it like this will need 12 scripts, and I would like to have just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to collect the data for each month of each year.

To achieve this you can use the following approach:

- open the 'year' dropdown and collect all displayed years except the 'año'
- open the 'month' dropdown and collect all displayed years except the 'mes'
- iterate over each year, inside of the 'years' loop iterate over each month. So you select, for example, year 2014 and then start selecting months Jan, Feb, Mar etc for this exact year. After all months are checked, you change the year, and start a new months loop.

So the final code may look like the following. You might consider changing the locators (I cannot test them obviously) and storing them in some constants, to not repeat yourself multiple times.

Also, you can pre-define months and years in some static tuples, instead of collecting them from the page (if they are not dynamic).

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.aduanas.gob.do/estadisticas/dinamicas/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# open dropdown menu for years, and collect all displayed years
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]'))).click()
years = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]/option') if el.text and el.text != 'Año']
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]'))).click()

# open dropdown menu for months, and collect all displayed month
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="month"]'))).click()
months = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="month"]/option') if el.text and el.text != 'Mes']
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="month"]'))).click()

for year in years:
    # select year
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="year"]'))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="year"]/option[text()="{year}"]'))).click()
    for month in months:
        # select each month one by one
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="month"]'))).click()
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="month"]/option[text()="{month}"]'))).click()

        # parse the displayed data here
        # parse the displayed data here
        # parse the displayed data here
        # parse the displayed data here

        print(f"Handled '{month}' month of the '{year}' year.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to loop, now I have to continue writing the code to download all the information.